# ruby で更新処理が反映されない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

rubyで作成されたプログラムについて教えて頂きたく質問させて頂きました。
model.saveで保存がされる値と、保存されない値があり原因がわからずに困っております。

Controllerのstore.to_not_verified.saveでは
verification_statusの値を正常に更新が出来ているのですが
なぜか、
store.to_verified.save
では、値が更新されずに困っております・・・。

store.to_verified.saveの時にも、値は更新はされないのですが
saveでエラー等は出ておりません。
validateにも引っかかっておりません。

rubyは触り始めたばかりで、根本的に何か足りない事があるのかもしれないのですが、原因をご教授頂けませんでしょうか。

何卒、宜しくお願い致します。

Store.rb

```
# Table name: stores
#
#  id                    :integer          not null, primary key
#  created_at            :datetime         not null
#  updated_at            :datetime         not null
#  verification_status   :integer          default(0), not null
#  verified_at           :datetime
class Store < ActiveRecord::Base

    validates :verification_status,
        :inclusion => {
        :in => [ 0, 1, 2, 3 ],
        :allow_nil => true
    }
    validates :verified_at, :timeliness => { :type => :datetime, :allow_nil => true }

    def to_not_verified
        self.verified_at = nil
        self.verification_status = 2
        self
    end

    def to_verified
        self.verified_at = nil
        self.verification_status = 1
        self
    end
end
```

Controller

```
def verified
    @verification = UserVerification.find(params[:id])

    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
        store = Store.find(1)
        store.to_verified.save
        # store.to_not_verified.save
    end

    rescue => e
        render action: "show", notice: 'Failed User verification.'
    else
        redirect_to admin_user_verifications_path, notice: 'User verification was successfully updated.'
end
```

Comment: 画面を操作したときのログも追記してください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

active record が .save して更新に(しれっと)失敗した際には、 そのオブジェクト自身から、何故更新に失敗したのかを取得できるようになっています。

```
raise store.errors.to_s if store.errors.present?
```

などを仕込んでみたりすると、開発中に何か意図しない挙動があれば、それが分かるかもしれません。

Comment: 返信が遅く申し訳ございません。ご教授ありがとうございます！